# Services consumes Products Vtiger 6.2.0

Tags: vtiger

Here it is.
When I create a New Service I need It to take some producs from producs molude. Is it prosible to create/program that?

Basicaly, Every time a sell a service it should "discount" producs stock.

Comment: Your question is lacking some of the required information. Can you please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)? Thanks!

Comment: I've posted it in wrong place.
It should be in vtiger experts forum, I'm sorry.
Here is for code.